Conditional Probability and Betting Stakes Problem
I recently came across a conditional probability problem that's used in a betting scenario( problem attached below). And my question is how does one know which stake to use for a given bet in order to avoid a sure-loss contract? For example, why does Sly in the problem use a stake of Q for betting Against B?
Conditional Probability Problem
Thank you.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

@JoséCarlosSantos Sorry about that. I will edit my post once I'm back at my computer in a couple of hours.
